# In Coq, is there a way to see the tactics applied by tauto?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a way to see the tactics applied by tauto? I.e., run tauto and get a list of tactics to apply (not including tauto)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tauto is a tactic directly written in OCaml, so it does not apply other tactics - it constructs a proof term. But you can have a look at the proof term it constructs.

E.g.

```
Goal forall P Q : Prop, P /\ Q -> P.
tauto.
Show Proof.
```

results in:

```
(fun (P Q : Prop) (H : P /\ Q) => and_ind (fun (H0 : P) (_ : Q) => H0) H)
```

The `fun (P Q : Prop) (H : P /\ Q)` corresponds to `intros P Q H`. Then it uses `and_ind` with a function as argument. This corresponds to `exact (and_ind (fun P' Q' => P') H).`. As you can see the trick is in the construction of the function argument of `and_ind`.

It is instructive to look at these proof terms, but if you would do the proof manually, you would usually do it in a different way than tauto does.

And if you look at proof terms of tauto, isolate the goal you proof with tauto - otherwise the proof term will be hard to digest.

Comment: But `tauto` is mostly defined in Ltac, not OCaml, in the file `theories/Init/Tauto.v`.

Comment: The code in `theories/Init/Tauto.v` is just some pre massaging of the goal to bring it into a form which uses less definitions. The real work is done in the tactic defined via `Declare ML Module "tauto_plugin".`.

Comment: I disagree; most of the real work is done by the Ltac tactic `tauto_intuit`, and the plugin is just used to define a few helper tactics, most noticeably `flatten_contravariant_{conj,disj}` (which seem like they could be defined in Ltac, or at least close approximations) and several tactics to inspect the shape of inductive types.